# Can someone guide me through these two convergence & divergence problems?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

1. $A_n = \cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})$
2. $A_n = \frac{\ln(3n)}{\ln(n)}$

---

So, for the first one, it looks like I'll have to use the squeeze theorem.

$ -1\le \cos(\frac{n\pi}{2}) \le 1$

I'm slightly confused, am I able to take the limit of $-\frac{n}{2}$ and the limit of $\frac{n}{2}$ These would come up with different limits though.

---

For the second one, it comes out as infinity/infinity so I'll have to use L'Hospital's rule and take the derivative.

My derivative, using the quotient rule, comes out as:

$\frac{ \ln(n)*\frac{1}{n} - \ln(3n)(\frac{1}{n})} {(\frac{1}{n})^2}$

This leaves me with $\frac{\infty - \infty} {0} $

The top is an indeterminate form, but the bottom is 0. Do I take the derivative again, or is the answer 0?

Comment: For $\cos\left(\tfrac{n\pi}{2}\right)$, what is its value when $n=1,2,3,4$?

Comment: There is no quotient rule in L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @JohnD Quotient rule for taking derivatives is what I was referring to. At Antonio, {0, -1, 0, -1}... I assume your point is that it goes from -1 to 0 not to 1.

Comment: But L'Hopital's says $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)\over g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}{f'(x)\over g'(x)}$, not $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\left({f(x)\over g(x)}\right)'$.

Comment: Ah! Wow I can't believe I overlooked that! Thanks for the info John. I'll continue conversing on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean the limit of the sequence where $a_n$ defines the $n$th term of the sequence...

$\cos(n\pi/2)=\{0,-1,0,1,0,\dots\}$ so $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(n\pi/2)$ does not exist.

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ln(3n)\over \ln(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty} {{3\over 3n}\over {1\over n}}=1$

Comment: For the first one, if the limit doesn't exist, is there any way to know whether the sequence is divergent or convergent?

Comment: When the limit does not exist, we say that the sequence diverges.

Comment: So, the 3 results for divergent sequences are: $\infty, -\infty$, and D.N.E. Anything else is considered convergent?

Comment: Think about it like this: if there is a (finite) real number which is the limit of the sequence, we say the sequence converges. Otherwise, the sequence diverges. You described three ways in which a sequence could diverge (by tending to $\infty$, tending to $-\infty$, or by remaining remaining bounded but simply not settling to a fixed number.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again (I'll delete this comment after you reply to avoid going off topic), if the sequence is $(n+e^n)^\frac{1}{n}$ what would the derivative be? I came up with: $\frac{1}{n}(n+e^n)^\frac{1-n}{n} * e^n$